# Haskell ASCII codes

Tags: haskell, module, ascii

I'm trying to make a function that takes an ***a*** (which can be any type: int, char...) and creates a list which has that input replicated the number of times that corresponds to its ASCII code.

I've created this:

> toList n = replicate (fromEnum n) n

When trying to use the function in the cmd it says it could match the expected type int with char, **however** if i use my function directly in the cmd with an actual value it does what it's supposed.

What i mean is: toList 'a' --> gives me an error

replicate (fromEnum 'a') 'a' --> gives a result without problem

I've loaded the module Data.Char (ord)

How can I fix this, and why does this happens?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're missing is a type declaration.  You say that you want it to be able to take *any* type, but what you really want is `toList` to take something that is an instance of `Enum`.  When you play around with it in GHCi, it'll let you do `let toList n = replicate (fromEnum n) n`, because GHCi will automatically pick some defaults that seem to make sense, but when compiling a module with GHC, it won't work without the type declaration.  You want

```
toList :: (Enum a) => a -> [a]
toList n = replicate (fromEnum n) n
```

The reason why you have to have the `(Enum a) =>` in the type signature is because `fromEnum` has the type signature `(Enum a) => a -> Int`.  So you see it doesn't just take *any* type, only those that have an instance for `Enum`.

Comment: Ohh right, I see! That's because only enumerable types have ASCII code? (Sorry I'm new to this)

Comment: @ipg24 The `Enum` typeclass has nothing to do with ASCII.  If you're coming from OOP, think of them as simply interfaces (for now, there's a bit more to them than that).  If something has an instance for `Enum` (i.e. an implementation of it), then it can be converted to and from an integer, there's really nothing more to it than that.

Comment: I don't see a reason why GHC could not infer that type?

Comment: @Ingo, hmm, you are correct, GHC can infer the type.  My first assumption (without running any code) was that the lack of type signature would be causing the error, but when I copied ipg24's code into a file and ran it, I didn't get an error.

Comment: @ipg24 Could you edit your post to include the error you're getting?  It's hard to tell what's wrong without it.

Comment: It only says 'Couldn't match expected type Int with Char'. However if I put  toList :: (Enum a) => a -> [a] in the file, it works perfectly

Comment: @bheklilr Ok, I don't know how this happened but, I removed the specification from the file (now it's the same as before) and suddenly it started doing everything perfectly fine, without errors! I don't know why but it happened. And this time I didn't import the Data.Char (ord). Can it possibly be because of that?

Comment: @ipg24 Data.Char shouldn't have anything to do with it.  That's quite odd.  Can you tell me which version of GHC you're using (`ghc --version`)?

Comment: @bheklilr Its the 2013.2.0.0 version, downloaded it a couple of days ago

Comment: @ipg24 That's the same version I'm using.  I don't know what your error was then, maybe you had a typo that got fixed somewhere along the way without being noticed?

Comment: @bheklilr I don't know, maybe... Thanks a lot for the help anyway :D